# Return Parent Child json serialized object with SQLAlchemy - lazy loading issue

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I'm trying to use a generic query to select a parent class with all its children classes.

The query looks like this:

```
def get_data(session: Session, table, data_filter):
try:
    data = session.query(table).filter_by(**data_filter).first()
    return data
except SQLAlchemyError as e:
    raise e
```

I'm not sure if the issue is the lazy loading but whenever I run the server I only get the data regarding the parent class.
Here's an example of the model I'm using:

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user_account"

    email: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(60), primary_key=True)
    username: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(30))
    password: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(BYTEA(60))
    firstname: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(30))
    lastname: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(30))

    domainName = relationship("DomainName", cascade="all, delete-orphan", 
    backref="user_account", lazy=False)


class DomainName(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user_domain"
    domain_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    user_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("user_account.email"))
    domain_name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(30))
```

My service just return the get_data call.
If I use the debugger I can see all the data (in the user object the "domainName" child object is populated without even interacting with the IDE). But when returned to postman, I only have the User fields (minus DomainName):

```
{
"email": "r@tester.com",
"username": "r",
"password": "",
"firstname": "r",
"lastname": "o"
}
```

Comment: You need to provide more code around how you are returning the results in your response. Are you setting a schema for your `response_model` for your route?

Comment: I'm simply returning it as is for now. But I found the problem I think

Answer (score 0):

I had to update the query function and not make it a generic function:

```
def get_user(session: Session, data_filter):
    return session.query(User).options(joinedload(User.domainName)).filter_by(**data_filter).first()
```